# MySQL Workbench not opening on ubuntu

Tags: sql, mysql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

While I am trying to open my installed MySQL workbench it is not opening, I try to open using terminal it shows the below error:

**command:**

> `mysql-workbench`

**Error:**

```
> Workbench can't find libproj.so, some options may be unavailable.
> /usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libzip.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file
> or directory
```

I've tried to install broken packages and creating symbolic link but also I am not able to fix.

Can someone help to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome aboard, Monika :-) I think you ought to be asking this at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/904972/mysql-workbench-fails-to-launch

You may get answers!

Comment: Hey Monika! Show me an output of the command, please: `ldconfig -p | grep libzip`

Comment: Hi,Result for above command is `libzip.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libzip.so.1`

Comment: That's why WB cannot run. Workbench requires libzip.so.4 to run. So you need to upgrade to libzip4. Btw, libproj.so is optional lib so you can run WB without it.

Comment: after upgrading libzip4 result for above command is `libzip.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip.so.4
 libzip.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libzip.so.1
 libzip.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip.so` **now WB error is** `Workbench can't find libproj.so, some options may be unavailable.
/usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libpcrecpp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Ok now you have to install libpcrecpp and all of other libs that you don't have installed buy that're required by WB. Or you can add  MySQL APT repository - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/ - and install WB from there.

Answer (score 11):

if running *mysql-workbench* command gives following warning:

```
    Workbench can't find libproj.so, some options may be unavailable.
```

run this command to check if you have the above mentioned file :

```
 $ find / -name libproj.so 2> /dev/null
```

if not found, then run this command to install the lacking file dependency to remove the warning:

```
 $ sudo apt install libproj-dev proj-bin
```

It will remove the warning. Worked for me. Please try in your system. Below is my command output:

```
 $ find / -name libproj.so 2> /dev/null
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so
 $ mysql-workbench
 Found /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.15
```

(Note: even if this warning was there, my Workbench was still running properly. I followed the above mentioned steps just to get rid of that warning.)

Comment: just installig `libpro-dev` worked for me.

Comment: Found /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.15.      But still crashing, don't what is happening.  could any one help me?
In terminal I could see following statement
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
*** Segmentation fault

Comment: what does `2> /dev/null` do?

Comment: Every command produces some output (o/p). we can access those outputs using:
"1" represents "stdout" aspect of the o/p
"2" represents the "stderr" aspect of the o/p
"&" represents both the "stdout and stderr" aspect of the o/p

">" is a operator and is used to redirect output of command to another command or a file.

"/dev/null" is a standard null device where you send output that you want to be ignored/useless.


Conclusion: The "stderr" aspect of o/p of previous command is redirected to a null device. The final output will contain only the "stdout" part of the o/p only.

Answer (score 11):

#### Reinstalling workbench and doing `--fix-broken install` worked for me.

Details:

1. Uninstall workbench

   `sudo apt remove mysql-workbench`
2. Clean

   `sudo apt clean`

   `sudo apt autoremove`
3. Update repos

   `sudo apt update && apt upgrade`
4. Install workbench again

   `sudo apt install mysql-workbench`
5. The fix

   `sudo apt --fix-broken install`
6. Run workbench

   `mysql-workbench`